# Batch File for convert txt to CSV removes spaces and commas convert to columns

Tags: csv, batch-file, txt

I am new in batch file programs.

I have lots of text (.txt) files to convert to CSV. if using manual method with (copy-paste to excel) remove space or comma and convert to column it will take a lot of time.

I have an idea to create a batch file and put it in the same folder where the text (.txt file) will be converted to CSV when the batch file is run, it will automatically convert the text to CSV and create the CSV file.

The text file format is shown below

[image: Source textfile]

As text:

```
 ADINA: AUI version 9.3.1, 22 November 2017:  *** NO HEADING DEFINED ***
 Licensed from ADINA R&D, Inc.
 Finite element program ADINA, response range type load-step:
 Listing for zone EG1:
      POINT        NODAL_FORCE-R

 Time 1.40000E+01

 Element 101100 of element group 1

 Local node 1     -2.96954E+03
 Local node 2      2.96954E+03

 Element 101200 of element group 1

 Local node 1      1.31964E+04
 Local node 2     -1.31964E+04

 Element 101300 of element group 1

 Local node 1      1.38607E+04
 Local node 2     -1.38607E+04

 Element 101400 of element group 1

 Local node 1     -3.57060E+03
 Local node 2      3.57060E+03

 Element 102100 of element group 1

 Local node 1      2.22511E+04
```

besides that, I want to delete text in the red box. because I don't use it.

The CSV file I want to create is shown below

[image: CSV file as displayed by Excel]

Folder structure

[image: "Folder"]

Is there any solution for this batch file code?

Really appreciate your help. Thanks all!

Comment: Can you paste into the question a text version of the text file in your picture so that I don't have to type it in to test my answer?

Comment: Notepad++, for example, would be used to "replace in files". Very handy.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I have pasted it thank you for your help!

Comment: OP: This is a clear request for code since you have shown no attempt to solve the problem yourself. Please note stackoverflow.com <https://stackoverflow.com/> is not a
free script/code writing service. Edit *relevant section(s)* of 
what you have tried into your question (use cut/paste) & say 
where you are stuck. We can try to help with specific problems.
You should also read How do I ask a good question?
<https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask>. Having said that, and following the policy of "be nice", I'll not close this question, even though it's off-topic.

Comment: Also :please include graphics, don't link to them. That makes it easier to see the entire problem without switching back and forth.

Comment: What you have posted as a CSV file does not help at all. It appears to be an image of some content within a spreadsheet application, with center aligned content, empty lines, and multiple lines which are unrelated to each other. It is not a valid CSV, if that is what your content should contain.

Comment: @Magoo thank you for the advice.  sorry, I'm new in StackOverflow. I will be careful in the future. I wrote my own code but it didn't work perfectly. but now it can be solved using jerry's code.

Comment: @Compo Thank you for your code. Sorry, my bad, I forgot to explain the CSV image and ignore the alignment CSV. I attached the CSV that has edited. the main purpose is to move the text to the CSV column. without copy-paste, removes spaces and commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might do what you want:

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" goto FindFiles

:ProcessFile
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6" %%A in (%1) do (
if "%%A" == "Time" echo %%A,%%B
if "%%A" == "Local" echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D
if "%%A" == "Element" echo.
if "%%A" == "Element" echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F
if "%%A" == "Element" echo.
)
goto Exit

:FindFiles
for %%I in (*.txt) do call %0 %%I > %%~nI.csv
goto Exit

:Exit
```

When double-clicked it runs itself once for each *.txt file in the current folder.
Each file is processed by only saving lines starting with `Time`, `Local` or `Element` (adding blank lines when needed).
Each line that is saved has each space-separated value saved with commas between instead.

Comment: The posted source file contains, numbers in exponential base 10 format, and the resultant CSV looks as if it does not. Now for all we know, especially as the OP's example is using cell alignment, those changes have been made in Microsoft Excel by formatting the cells respectively. The point I'm making is that whilst it may be possible to create a file with a `.csv` extension, it is not possible to create a file which when opened in their spreadsheet application, will display like the one which the OP has posted as their intended result. You should also use `skip=9`, to omit the unwanted lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example for you to work through as part of your learning experience. The answer is designed to work only with the posted text file content you have provided. I will not be explaining anything within it, or changing anything due to subsequent changes to your originally posted task, *(as you have not attempted anything yourself)*.

```batch-file
@If Exist "force.txt" ((For /F "Skip=9 Tokens=1-7" %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%find.exe /N /V "" ^< "force.txt"'
) Do @If Not "%%M" == "" (Echo %%H,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M
    ) Else If Not "%%L" == "" (Echo %%H,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L
    ) Else If Not "%%K" == "" (Echo %%H,%%I,%%J.%%K
    ) Else If Not "%%J" == "" (Echo %%H,%%I,%%J
    ) Else If Not "%%I" == "" (Echo %%H,%%I
    ) Else If Not "%%H" == "" (Echo %%H) Else Echo=) > "force.csv")
```

Once inside your spreadsheet you will still need to incorporate your required cell alignment and formatting changes, if you want it to match your posted image.